# Why to use strict comparison in string status checking?

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

I oftentimes see answers using strict comparison (===) instead of normal comparison (==) on status checking, i.e. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState):

```
if(document.readyState === 'complete') ...
```

I would understand the reason if it were applied on empty string and the obtained value could be also other falsy value with different meaning. But when applied on non-empty string (like 'complete' in the sample), I believe the result is always the same for '==' and '==='. Is that so?

Some people measured that '===' can be faster, but I haven't seen a real world example where it would make any observable difference, so I don't take this micro-optimalization seriously.

On the other hand, anytime I see this operator, I read it as a warning "mind the type here!". But since document.readyState is always string, it annoys me that the original coder made me to study the code what other types there can appear - only to find out that only string.

To me, it is a strong reason to be polite to those who read my code and never use '===' when the type plays no role in the comparison.

Since '===' appears in similar cases in many SO answers and many expert pages, I would like to know if it is just social bandwagon or if there is any good reason why to use it in status checking.

Comment: It's just easier to use `===` everywhere and be absolutely sure that you're doing the correct comparison. Much more convenient from trying to second-guess yourself any time you see a `==` because *maybe* it was a typo or *maybe* it was intentional.

Comment: Really my only exception to "`===` everywhere" is the fairly common case of wanting to check a variable to see if it's "empty", and both `null` and `undefined` are in practical terms "empty", so only one `==` comparison (to `null`) is necessary.

Comment: @VLAZ I was tending to use this approach, but there are things like input values, localStorage items, WebSQL column type or HTTP response data where type auto changes to string. I find it redundant to explicitly change the type of once verified data only to 'use === everywhere' policy and started to use '==' allowing the variables to implicitly change the type to string. But I get the point, I can read '==' as "type can be different" in codes which prefer '===' (almost) everywhere.

Comment: javascript is full of archaic stuff (`var`, `with`, `__proto__` you name it) which should never be used in new code. `==` definitely belongs to this list. The best option to deal with it is to configure the linter to mark it as a syntax error and forget about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend always using '===' instead of '==' when *strict* equality checking is required, which it is in most cases, for this reason: it declares intent. When I see code with '===', I will read it as 'a must be referentially or primitively equal to b'. When I see '==', I will read it as 'a must be coercibly equal to b'. From that, I will judge what kind of goal the code / original programmer is trying to accomplish and how they are passing data around to get the job done. Essentially, it yields insight into the context of the application, the way data is being passed around, and how this function / method / code block fits into the picture.

With that being said, if I see someone do 'a == b' when they are both strings, I'm not going to get on any high horse and make a fuss about it.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I would make a fuss about it in only in some cases, like `function isHello(str) { return str==='hello'; }` and then `isHello(new String('hello'))` - false.

Comment: That is true, using the "String" object, instead of the primitive, will return false if references are different. For comparing the 'meanings', you can use '==' directly. You can also use new String('a').localeCompare('a').

Answer (score 1):

It always depends on what you want to achieve, and what you consider to be equal.

`==` is not always bad, but it often can lead to false assumptions.

If you have something like this:

```js
class TestA {
  toString() {
     return 'complete'
  }
}

class TestB {
  valueOf() {
     return 'complete'
  }
}

let testA = new TestA()
let testB = new TestB()
console.log(testA == 'complete')
console.log(testB == 'complete')
```

Then `testA == 'complete'` might be exactly what you want, but because it does an implicit cast, you might do a false assumption about it being a string when it evaluates to `true`.

So if you later want to call something like `substring` on it, or passing it to another function that expects an actual string, then it might fail with an unexpected error.

Using `===` over `==` is mostly about maintainability, if you start to refactor code or if you look at older code and you see a `==` you always need to think about if you really want to have an implicit cast at that point or if it this was an accident. So you need to follow the code flow or check if it was documented.

Using an explicitly and `===` does not prevent you from doing other mistakes, but it keeps the code consistent.